# Errors while registrate as user --php

Tags: php, registration

I am going to create a registration in php but it shows me the following errors:

**string(59) "insert into users (username,email,password)values('','','')" Duplicate entry '' for   key 'email'**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("university", $con);


$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES('{$_POST['uname']}', '{$_POST['pwd']}', '{$_POST['email']}')");
if (!$res) {

    echo "MYSQL ERROR ->" . mysql_error();
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(\'Regjistrimi u krye me sukses!\')</script>';
}
?>
```

This i the form in html. I cant see where it may be wrong

```
<div id="containt" align="right">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="registration_form"> 

        <table border="0">
    <tbody>

    <tr>
    <td><label for="name">Your Name*: </label> </td>
    <td><input id="name" maxlength="45" name="name" type="text" /> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label for="email">Email*:</label> </td>
    <td><input id="email" maxlength="45" name="email" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label for="username">Username*:</label> </td>
    <td><input id="username" maxlength="45" name="uname" type="text" /> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label for="password">Password*:</label></td>
    <td><input id="password" maxlength="45" name="pwd" type="password" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td align="right"><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Regjistro" /></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody></table>

    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Two things; 1. A record with the email already exists in your db.  2. Don't use email as your key; use an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do this all from one php file?  The best way would be to break it up into a php file to display your form and a php file to handle the submit logic, named submit.php or something similar.  And then in your form tag's action attribute, you would put "./submit.php"

-or-

If you are set on doing everything in the same page, wrap all of your submit logic inside of an if...

```
if(isset($_POST['uname'])){
    // write to the database inside of here
}
```

that way, you are only writing to the database if there is something in your $_POST array.

Comment: the problem is that i get this error before i write the email, after i open the page it shows me this error

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: uname in C:\xampp\htdocs\universiteti\index.php on line 92

Notice: Undefined index: pwd in C:\xampp\htdocs\universiteti\index.php on line 92

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\universiteti\index.php on line 92
MYSQL ERROR ->Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'                            where line 92 is $res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES('{$_POST['uname']}', '{$_POST['pwd']}', '{$_POST['email']}')");

Comment: It sounds like all your fields `$_POST['uname']` are blank, you are probably not passing them in from your form properly.

Comment: i just edited it and put even the form in html. Please take a look and see what is wrong

Comment: I've edited my answer, that should fix it.

Comment: where  should i put   if(isset($_POST['uname'])){
    // write to the database inside of here
}  right before the query?

Comment: yes, you should put the query and the results checking inside of the `{}` of that if statement

Comment: it now works :) thank you. The only problem now is that after registration it shows the message "passord or username wrong" instead of "successfully registrated"